# Sending spring integration jms message to specific queue (dynamically)

Tags: spring, jms, spring-integration, messaging, spring-jms

A simple message publisher looks like:

```
@Service("myPublisher")
public class MyPublisher{

   @Publisher(channel = "myChannel")
   public Message<?> sendMessage (Message<?> message) {
      return message;
   }
}
```

...and is configures like this:

```
<int:channel id="myChannel"/>   
<int-jms:outbound-channel-adapter channel="myChannel" destination="defaultDestination" session-transacted="true"/>
<bean class="org.springframework.integration.aop.PublisherAnnotationBeanPostProcessor"/>
```

The Problem is, this publisher sends messages to a prepared `defaultDestination`, but I need to send messages to different queues. In my case I need a message queue for every task in my application. The reason is, if I want to abort a task, I must remove the messages from the broker. If there are thousands of messages for one task, it is not a good practice to receive all messages with a selector. I need to to remove all messages of the aborted task from the message broker without receiving of a client. JMS only supports sending and receiving of messages. I must use the broker API (QPID) to remove the messages. The problem is, QPID doesn't support removing of messages by a selector, but it supports removing of queues.

I think, I need a PublisherFactory, with a function like this:

```
public class PublisherFactory {
    public MyPublisher getPublisher(String destinationName){...};
}

factory.getPublisher("testQueue");
```

This method should return a publisher that sends messages to the `testQueue`.

Or a service with a function like this:

```
public class PublisherService {
    public Message<?> sendMessage(Message<?> message, String desinationName){...};
}

service.sendMessage(new Message("test"), "testQueue");
```

In short words, all I want, is a service that sends a `Message` to a specific destination. The destination name should be set either as a param over method call or as a class variable over a factory.

I hope, someone has the solution of my problem. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `<int-jms:outbound-channel-adapter>` can be configured not only to the static `destination`, but with some dynamic behavior to determine `destination` at runtime using SpEL against request message.

```
destination-expression="headers.destination"
```

From other side `@Publisher`'s AOP allows to build a message to publish not only just with the `payload` as a `return` value by default, but with more smart logic. For example:

```
@Publisher(channel="annotationConfigRegistrationTest")
@Payload("#return + #args.lname")
public String setName(String fname, String lname, @Header("x") int num) {
    return fname + " " + lname;
}
```

In this case the message to publish will have a `payload` like return value, plus a `lname` param.
The `@Header("x")` will populate to that message an `x` header with `num` as value.

Since your `sendMessage` methods returns whole `Message<?>`, you just need to build a new message there and add mentioned above `destination` header, based on the stuff for current state.

HTH

Comment: I just added a message bean with own header and payload annotations for class variables. So have the same message type with all header informations on publisher and on handler side :)

Thanks for your answer. :) The problem of using SpEL is, I have an undefined number of parallel running publishers. That means, every publisher needs his own channel and channel-adapter. Sure, I can use a blocking singleton service which gives desintinationName for using SpEL, but than I take the synchronization of the publishers from spring integration. I think that is not the best solution for my problem. :(

Comment: ??? If you populate a header to each message as I recommended there won't be need in `sync` block, because the SpEL is evaluated against each message independently.

Comment: Oh....I'm sorry. I think I misunderstood you. :D Now, I know what you mean... I will try it and comment again after some tests :)

Comment: Wow, It works :) That was simple. Thank you very much.